# Multiple connections with node cluster and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

im using socket.io with sticky session (https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session). I have a little chat application and always when im using 2 or more sockets on one one machine the `socket.on(...)` event listener is firing very very slow. When i'm using only one socket-connection for each cluster everything works fine and fast. What could be the cause. Could it be because of sticky session?

**Edit:**

This is the socket- connect function (of my worker - clusters):

```
WebSockets.on('connect', function (socket) {
        console.log(`${process.pid}`);
        //send data example: socket.emit('news', {a: "b"});
        //TODO: implement switch case that validates which chat type it is. 
        //TODO: why is the event so slow when using 2 connections?: https://socketio.slack.com/messages/C02AS4S1H/
        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            console.log("sending message: " + msg)
            try {
                //send the message to all other cluster-workers:
                process.send({ chat_message: msg });
            } catch (e) { }
        });
        //if the cluster gets a message then he sends it to the user, if its the correct user
        function message_handler(msg) {
            try {
                //TODO: send message only to the correct users
                if (msg != null && msg.chat_message != null) {
                    WebSockets.emit('chat message', msg.chat_message);
                }
            } catch (e) { }
        }
        process.on('message', message_handler);
        //When the socket disconnects:
        socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
            //remove the event listener:
            process.removeListener('message', message_handler);
        });

    });
```

Explanation: I'm sending all the data i get from the socket to all the other clusters. Then I catch them with:

```
process.on('message', message_handler);
```

To send incomming chat messages.

I created the Clusters with sticky session like in the example (https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session)

Comment: I rather doubt this is something we can help with given only this much information.  We'd probably need to know more about the stick session configuration, your cluster configuration and your actual socket.io code.  One thing you should check is whether the clients are getting a good socket.io connection or whether they're constantly spinning try to connect over and over or even polling?

Comment: I added some code to my question

Comment: Are you only getting the one expected `connect` message per client?  Can you tell if each client is successfully connecting with a sticky socket.io connect and NOT using polling?  My guess is that the stick-session stuff isn't working properly and your clients are not sticky and thus are bouncing around between cluster processes and that makes things appear to be really slow.  You could also tell the client to force use of webSocket as the transport so the client won't initially poll (like socket.io normally does for the first few seconds) and that might help too.

Comment: But, if the stick session is not working properly, you need to fix that anyway because you want any reconnects to be sticky if a connection drops and has to re-establish.

Comment: there are 3 requests done by socket.io: `/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M1Cdbw2`, `/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M1CdbwM&sid=YWQ8uCkgKo421n3CAAAB` and this one is the websocket itself: `/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=YWQ8uCkgKo421n3CAAAB`

Comment: There is "polling" included as one parameter. So how can I check if socket.io is polling in the socket-connection ?

Comment: You can just look in the network tab in the Chrome debugger and watch what the client is doing when it connects to your server.  A normal socket.io connection would see something like three http requests, then it would switch to a webSocket and then no additional http requests related to socket.io.  A connection stuck in polling will continue making more http requests over time.  If you change the client config to force webSocket as the transport, then you should see only one initial http request that initiates the webSocket connection and then no more http requests related to socket.io.

Comment: Ok this is the case (there are only 2 requests and the third websocket) then there are no more http-requests following. So this should be fine

Comment: It's interesting that if im sending a message I see in the developer console that this message was sent to the server. But the server needs sometimes 3 - 8 seconds to fire the `socket.on(...)` function

Comment: And sometimes the socket - connection is sending frames with numbers in it (for example 2 or 3). I'm not sure if this is the proper behaviour.

Comment: Regular small frames are likely ping and pong messages which are normal, part of a keep-alive strategy.  I don't know why you're getting a delay.  Is your server being asked to do anything else that could keep it busy for a few seconds at a time?

Comment: No. There are only the Websocket-connections that are keeping my server busy. Nothing else.

Comment: Another weird thing is that if im sending 2 messages while im connected with multiple sockets the `socket.on(...)` function is called immediately after the second message. Such as it would refresh itself after the second message.

Comment: Wild guess that your socket.io connection us not stable and regularly has to reconnect.

Comment: How could i fix this ?

Comment: Too hard for us to know what could be the problem without having a reproducible server in front of us that we could instrument, examine logs, examine client connections, turn on socket.io debugging, etc...